# gitlab get all commit messages for external project tool API

Tags: gitlab-api

I need to figure out how I can read out all git commit messages. We have an external project management System and we want to collect all commit messages in there. Is there anyway to read out all commits?

I found the API to get the commits for every project, but i dont want to configure every project in my tool.

Is there any better way?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in the Gitlab API is project based, so you have to first retrieve the projects (or already know the project IDs you need) before you can grab items like Merge Requests, Issues, Pipelines, or Commits. For now there's no other way, and from here (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/graphql/#available-queries) it looks like their new GraphQL implementation (that will eventually replace the current API) will operate the same way.